# Elixir: What happen to a process after done executing the function

Tags: process, elixir

I'm trying to understand the differences between `spawn` and `spawn_link`, but can't quite grasp what happens when the function the process executes ends.

```elixir
defmodule SendAndDie do
  def send_and_die(target) do
    send(target, "Goodbye")
    # Process.exit(self, :boom)
  end
end

dying_process = spawn_link(SendAndDie, :send_and_die, [self])
:timer.sleep(500)
IO.puts("Dying process is alive: #{Process.alive?(dying_process)}")
receive do
  msg -> IO.puts(msg)
end
```

I expected the main process to fail, as it linked to a process that clearly died before the end of the program. However, the "Goodbye" message is printed and then the program exits normally. Changing `spawn_link` to `spawn` have no effect.

When I uncomment the `Process.exit` in line 4 I do see the difference between `spawn` and `spawn_link` (the later stops the whole program while the former doesn't). But, the `Process.exit` is the last execution in the `send_and_die` function. Isn't the process going to exit anyway when the function ends?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the erlang manual on processes](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html)

> The default behaviour when a process receives an exit signal with an exit reason other than normal, is to terminate and in turn emit exit signals with the same exit reason to its linked processes.

When the initial function of the process returns it terminates with reason `normal`, so this default behaviour does not bring down the linked process.

Comment: Amazing! Changing the exit signal from :boom to :normal caused the process to terminate normally, as it would if the function returns. Therefore, the linked (main) process wasn't killed. Thanks a lot!